# Unbounded convex domains in 2D

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, curves

Let $\gamma$ be a smooth planar curve. Assume that $\gamma$ divides the plane into two domains and, it addition, that one of these domains is unbounded and convex. What can be said about the behavior of the curvature of $\gamma$ at infinity: does it tend to zero, if yes, is there a more precise asymptotics which holds in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the curvature does not need to go to $0$.  Consider starting with a polygonal curve with infinitely many corners (e.g. the line segments joining $[n,n^2]$ to $[n+1, (n+1)^2]$ for integers $n$), and smoothing out the corners.  If the angle at the $x=n$ corner changes by $\epsilon_n$ and the piece of curve where this change occurs has length $\delta_n$, the maximum curvature in this interval will be at least $\epsilon_n/\delta_n$.  Thus if $\epsilon_n/\delta_n$ does not go to $0$, neither will the curvature.